# Websocket Sampler error - java.base/java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:970)

Tags: jmeter

I am using Websocket Sampler plugin in JMeter but getting below error during test execution.

- Unexpected error: null
  `java.base/java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:970) java.base/java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:892) JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.ServiceSocket.getResponseMessage(ServiceSocket.java:149) JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler.sample(WebSocketSampler.java:159) org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)` org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
  java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)``

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the server doesn't return any response, most probably your websocket connection has failed somewhere somehow. It's hard to say why without seeing your configuration and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Anyway I would recommend considering switching to [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/)

[image]

this plugin is way more powerful in terms of integrating with JMeter's [SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SSL_Manager), [header](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and [cookie](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) managers and supporting more features/use cases. Check out [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers) article for more information.